# C# - SQL query returning items affected

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an SQL query which creates a temp table, inserts records into it and then iterates through these records either inserting new records or updating existing records as required.  I keep a count of these as 2 local variables '@updated' and '@inserted',.  I want to return these values so at the end of the query I have added :

```
SELECT @updates as UPDATES, @inserted AS INSERTED
```

When I run my query from QA I get the correct output stating the records updated and inserted.  However when I run the query from C# I am using

```
SqlDataReader myReader = command.ExecuteReader();
if (myReader.Read())
{
    updates = myReader.GetInt32(0);
    inserts = myReader.GetInt32(1);
}
```

but I get an exception as it says that the data is null.  There are 2 fields in the returned row according to field count but they are both null.  Not sure why?

Comment: did you check what is going behind the scenes when is run from C#? I mean using a profiler ...

Comment: Your code seems right. Is the `SELECT` you posted the only result of the SQL script?

Comment: Also, show us how you create the command

Comment: Does the temp table still exists when you select the records? Do you use  #table to ##table? Does it have to be multiuserfriendly?

Answer (score 0):

As Brett said - port this into a stored procedure.  I'm sure you'll be glad you did at a later date..

One more thing that MIGHT give you an issue is the types (on the c# end)

So, Id make sure you convert your results into an INT.

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, @updates) as UPDATES, CONVERT(INT, @inserted) AS INSERTED
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All - you put me on the right track letting me know that it looked correct.  Turns out to be a rookie mistake - I was incrementing @updates and @inserts but I hadn't initialised it to 0 first so the query was actually working as expected.  No idea why it worked in QA but works a treat now.